# How to (box) unwrap a model in three.js on the fly?

Tags: three.js

My game has a very simplistic retro pixel style, where all the models use flat mapping (box unwrap) for the models. The unwrap is always the same process in my modeling program: selecting a box unwrap modifier with the same settings.

This gets tedious as I need to explain other people how to unwrap and we all make mistakes sometimes or forget to unwrap some part of a mesh, requiring a full re-export.

It would be better if I could code this somehow, so other people don't have to mess around with the UV's and can just focus on the model. The model gets materials assigned automatically in-game, just the UV's should ideally be generated on the fly when I load the models in three.js.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a modelling question and has nothing to do with three.js

Comment: @gaitat Sorry if I'm unclear, I updated the question again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe check this link:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2065#issuecomment-6352320

this is about planar mapping and only works for Three.Face3, triangles but it is very easy to add the fourth UV-coordinate. If you got this working with the right scale based on your object, you can then iterate over all of your object's face normals and check the side they are most facing to. And then, you do this planar mapping algorithm for  every side and voila, box mapping :)  Hope this helps!